# sql join with where and 1-n connection

Tags: mysql, sql

We have 2 tables:

```
UserTable

userid   username
1        test
2        test2
3        test3


UserStatus

statusid userid status
1        1      1
2        1      3
3        1      7
4        2      1
```

Now we need a user list with users that do **not** have status 3.

Have any ideas?

Comment: Gotta be a duplicate ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM UserTable
WHERE userid NOT IN
(SELECT userid FROM UserStatus WHERE status = 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select u.userid,
  u.username
from usertable u
where not exists (select s.userid
                  from userstatus s
                  where s.status = 3
                    and u.userid = s.userid);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8be95/5)

Answer (score 2):

You could use NOT IN:

```
SELECT usertable.*
FROM usertable
WHERE userid NOT IN (SELECT userid from userstatus where status=3)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75694/2).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT username from UserTable
WHERE userid NOT IN (SELECT userid FROM UserStatus WHERE status = 3)
```